# C++: how to specify thread function in a complex template class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, reference

The minimized code is as follows. The goal is to copy data in parallel using C++ standard threading library from a template class. The object of the Source must be transmitted as a reference because I need to use polymorphism feature of C++. The data type can be various complex object instead of `int` in the minimized code. The compile error is

> error C3867: 'Array::Thread': non-standard syntax; use '&' to
>   create a pointer to member

I have read many related threads from internet but they are all too simple to apply. I also tried using functor to specify the thread worker function but failed. So, how to fix the issue in this complex template situation (you can use functor)? I am using Visual Studio 2015 but I think similar error message would appear on Linux. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template < typename U >
class Source {
public:
    Source(U data) : data(data) {}
    U Get() { return data; }
private:
    U data;
};

template < typename U >
class Array {
public:
    Array(U data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            t[i] = data;
    }
    void Thread(int i, Source<U>& source) {
        t[i] = source.Get();
    }
    void ThreadsWrapper(Source<U>& source) {
        vector<thread> threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            threads.push_back(thread(Thread, i, ref(source)));

        for (auto & t : threads)
            t.join();
    }
private:
    U t[10];
};

int main()
{
    Source<int> c(7);
    Array<int> a(2);
    a.ThreadsWrapper(c);
}
```

Comment: Two things: A member function needs an object to be called on; And how about trying to do what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: A simple tip: In the for loop that goes through threads, you shouldn't name the variable the same as your member variable in class, it makes the code badly readable.

Comment: I tried this->Thread but got the same error. Frankly I'm not very clear what the message asks me to do. I added & before Thread and the error changes to "error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression".

Comment: The Thread is an method so you should use somehting more like std::bind(&Array::Thread, this) or just use &Array::Thread, this, i...

Comment: Also this case is pretty simple so I would advice using std::async with std::launch::async policy, which is a more modern solution than manually managing threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is "simply" syntax. What you need is this:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(&Array::Thread, this, i, ref(source)));
```

The first problem is that `Thread` is the name of a member function. To take its address you need `&Array::Thread`. That's (more or less) what the error message is telling you. The second problem is that member functions have to be called on objects, which is why you have to pass `this` when you create the thread.

Comment: Thank you.______________________

Comment: Is this de facto equivalent to the lambda solution in my answer? OP reports that this works whereas the other causes problems with the thread scheduler, which sounds a bit dubious to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a lambda:

```
threads.push_back(thread([&]{ Thread(i, source); }));
```

This avoids all potentially hard-to-read workarounds with `std::bind`, `std::ref` or similar constructs.

Your original error message was caused by the fact that you indirectly tried to call `Thread` without an instance of `Array`. You attempted to construct the `std::thread` with the `Thread` function, but failed to tell it that it should be called on `this`.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much!

Comment: This method can pass the compiler but the threading scheduling is messed up on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with g++ 4.8.4. It can be shown by outputting thread number i at the beginning of the Thread function. The messy threading scheduling was not discovered until a whole-night's debugging that almost drove me mad. Another answer works so I have to accept that one; sorry. PS: this answer works fine on Windows and in debug mode on Linux, but messes up in release mode.

Comment: @user5280911: I cannot imagine why the lambda solution would cause that behaviour and taking the address of the function would not. The effect should be identical: `Array` is called on `this`. My gut feeling tells me that you have undefined behaviour somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @ChristianHackl -- I agree with you: the differences between our two solutions wouldn't (absent compiler or library bugs) lead to the kind of problem described.